# how to check the blank option?

Tags: python, django

please help fix the code.

I have a form:

```
<form class="left filter" action="/userprofile/friends_search/" method="GET">
    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label lbl_name" for="fld_name">Имя</label>

        <input class="fld_name" type="text" name="fld_name" id="fld_name" value="">
    </div>          

    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label lbl_birth_date" for="fld_birth_date">Дата рождения</label>

        <input class="fld_birth_date datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text" name="fld_birth_date" id="fld_birth_date" value="">
    </div>                  

    <div class="cell">
        <input class="submit btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name="fld_submit" id="fld_submit" value="Найти">
    </div>
</form>
```

when you send it passed the following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/friends_search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=aRivIk9zMHSEKLFfWc5sTerJqlvpiX96&fld_name=&fld_birth_date=
```

the problem is that the controller can not I check parameter search_result a null value:

```
@login_required 
def friends_search(request):
    search_result = None

    if request.method == 'GET' and not request.GET.get('fld_name'):
        search_result = 'empty'
    else:
        search_result = 'full'

        with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "search_result.txt"), "wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes(search_result, 'UTF-8'))      

    t = loader.get_template('friends_search.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'search_result': search_result,
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

resulting in the debug file search_result.txt is written "full". but should "empty"

Comment: Are you sending post request ?

Comment: Try `print request.method` the line before the `if statement` to make sure the `request.method` is in fact `GET`. My guess is that the `if statement` fails at the `request.method == 'GET'` point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all just Print out these two conditions separately, e.g.

```
print request.method, request.method == 'GET', not request.GET.get('fld_name')
```

and see which one's failing.

If **request.method is not GET** than debug why not, and **if it is GET** then try this:

```
request.method.lower() == 'get'
```

If second one fails (**which shouldn't**) then try this:

`request.GET.get('fld_name') != ''`  #But this would leave the case of None unhandled

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required 
def friends_search(request):
    search_result = None

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if request.POST.get('fld_name'):
            try:
                fld_name = request.POST.get('fld_name')
                search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(nickname__icontains=fld_name))     
                if not search_result:
                    search_result = 'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.'
            except Exception as exc:
                search_result = 'В данный момент доступ к базе данных невозможен. Попробуйте повторить ваш запрос позже.'   

    if isinstance(search_result, str):
        search_result_type = 'str'
    elif isinstance(search_result, dict):
        search_result_type = 'dict'
    else:
        search_result_type ='none'

    t = loader.get_template('friends_search.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'CHOICES_gender': UserProfile.get_CHOICES_gender(),
        'CHOICES_status': UserProfile.get_CHOICES_status(),
        'city_list': UserProfile.get_city_list(),
        'search_result': search_result,
        'search_result_type': search_result_type,
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```